# Can windows lock the Comport number when enumerating new USB->Serial hardware

Tags: windows, registry, usbserial

I would love to know if Windows, Win10 in particular, has the ability to lock a comport number to USB-Serial. In a Point of Sale enterprise environment, I have a golden image that techs use to restore the image when a new POS is installed, hard drives are replaced, etc. Our new hardware uses USB->Serial, specifically CP21xx chips/driver for the comports. Each time the image is loaded down on different hardware, windows enumerates different comport numbers. I need them to be consistent.
Different thoughts on how to handle it.
I read something about a registry hack to ignore the serial number. I could not tell much "how to" detail from the article. Maybe I am using the wrong search words.

Different tack, I did find this SO thread [When I removed the driver com port programatically, it is removed. But when reinstalled the driver on com port, the com port number is increased?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834667/when-i-removed-the-driver-com-port-programatically-it-is-removed-but-when-rein) I do have a bat file that cleans up the AD, other GUID, IP, etc. Maybe if the answer to the thread works and I can remove the current settings, so that Windows would reassign the same comport numbers to different serial number hardware.
Again, I am hoping I was missing something on the registry hack or some other way to lock the comport numbers.

FYI, Here is the registry hack, maybe I mistyped something?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM]
"\\Device\\Silabser0"="COM4"
"\\Device\\Silabser1"="COM5"
"\\Device\\Silabser2"="COM6"
"\\Device\\Silabser3"="COM7"


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports]
"COM4:"="9600,n,8,1"
"COM5:"="9600,n,8,1"
"COM6:"="9600,n,8,1"
"COM7:"="9600,n,8,1"


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_00\8&35fb885d&0&0000]
"FriendlyName"="Silicon Labs Dual CP2105 USB to UART Bridge: Enhanced COM Port (COM4)"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_00\8&35fb885d&0&0000\Device Parameters]
"PortName"="COM4"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_01\8&35fb885d&0&0001]
"FriendlyName"="Silicon Labs Dual CP2105 USB to UART Bridge: Standard COM Port (COM5)"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_01\8&35fb885d&0&0001\Device Parameters]
"PortName"="COM5"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_00\8&b6a3588&0&0000]
"FriendlyName"="Silicon Labs Dual CP2105 USB to UART Bridge: Enhanced COM Port (COM6)"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_00\8&b6a3588&0&0000\Device Parameters]
"PortName"="COM6"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_01\8&b6a3588&0&0001]
"FriendlyName"="Silicon Labs Dual CP2105 USB to UART Bridge: Standard COM Port (COM7)"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_01\8&b6a3588&0&0001\Device Parameters]
"PortName"="COM7"



[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_00\8&35fb885d&0&0000]
"FriendlyName"="Silicon Labs Dual CP2105 USB to UART Bridge: Enhanced COM Port (COM4)"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_00\8&35fb885d&0&0000\Device Parameters]
"PortName"="COM4"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_01\8&35fb885d&0&0001]
"FriendlyName"="Silicon Labs Dual CP2105 USB to UART Bridge: Standard COM Port (COM5)"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_01\8&35fb885d&0&0001\Device Parameters]
"PortName"="COM5"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_00\8&b6a3588&0&0000]
"FriendlyName"="Silicon Labs Dual CP2105 USB to UART Bridge: Enhanced COM Port (COM6)"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_00\8&b6a3588&0&0000\Device Parameters]
"PortName"="COM6"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_01\8&b6a3588&0&0001]
"FriendlyName"="Silicon Labs Dual CP2105 USB to UART Bridge: Standard COM Port (COM7)"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USB\VID_10C4&PID_EA70&MI_01\8&b6a3588&0&0001\Device Parameters]
"PortName"="COM7"


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\COM Name Arbiter\Devices]
"COM3"=-
"COM4"="\\\\?\\usb#vid_10c4&pid_ea70&mi_00#8&35fb885d&0&0000#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}"
"COM5"="\\\\?\\usb#vid_10c4&pid_ea70&mi_01#8&35fb885d&0&0001#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}"
"COM6"="\\\\?\\usb#vid_10c4&pid_ea70&mi_00#8&b6a3588&0&0000#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}"
"COM7"="\\\\?\\usb#vid_10c4&pid_ea70&mi_01#8&b6a3588&0&0001#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}"
"COM8"=-
"COM9"=-
"COM10"=-
"COM11"=-
"COM12"=-
"COM13"=-
"COM14"=-
"COM15"=-
"COM16"=-


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\COM Name Arbiter]
"ComDB"=hex:7f,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\COM Name Arbiter\Devices]
"COM3"=-
"COM4"="\\\\?\\usb#vid_10c4&pid_ea70&mi_00#8&35fb885d&0&0000#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}"
"COM5"="\\\\?\\usb#vid_10c4&pid_ea70&mi_01#8&35fb885d&0&0001#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}"
"COM6"="\\\\?\\usb#vid_10c4&pid_ea70&mi_00#8&b6a3588&0&0000#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}"
"COM7"="\\\\?\\usb#vid_10c4&pid_ea70&mi_01#8&b6a3588&0&0001#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}"
"COM8"=-
"COM9"=-
"COM10"=-
"COM11"=-
"COM12"=-
"COM13"=-
"COM14"=-
"COM15"=-
"COM16"=-


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\COM Name Arbiter]
"ComDB"=hex:7f,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```